# Postgres query about the roles of each user

Tags: sql, postgresql, roles

I'm trying to make a query that shows the users and all the roles that they have.  I already know how to ask about the roles of one particular user:

```
SELECT oid, rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE
pg_has_role( 'name_of_user', oid, 'member');
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: add http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56096/how-to-get-all-roles-that-a-user-is-a-member-of-including-inherited-roles/56104#56104 to your question as a source of your query please

Answer (score 3):

run `psql -E` to see statements behind meta commands in psql:

```
vao=# \du
********* QUERY **********
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
**************************

                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 ro        | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rw        | Cannot login                                               | {}
 vao       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {ro,rw}
```